# OneupUploaderBundle(blueimp) all files

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, oneupuploaderbundle

I used `OneupUploaderBundle`, fronted: `jQuery-File-Upload`.

Now, I can upload file and add records to entity, but default, doesn't show all uploaded files. When I added files to list and clicked "Start Upload", I can see the files in the list, after refresh, list is erased.

```
 public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $object = new file();
        $object->setFilename($file->getPathName());

        $this->manager->persist($object);
        $this->manager->flush();
        //$files = $this->getFiles($request->files);
        $response['files']= array(
            array(
                'name' => $file->getPathName(),
                'url' => $file->getPathName()
            )
        );
    }
```

Do I need to use other method to response?